# Selecting other hierarchies in dimensions

Tags: mdx, mondrian

I've googled the error message and various other keywords, but haven't
found anything similar enough to my own problem that I could apply it.

In my schema, I have the following dimension:

```
<Dimension name="Chip">
  <Hierarchy hasAll="true" primaryKey="chip_id">
    <Table name="chip"/>
    <Level name="Reference Designator" column="ux" type="Integer"/>
    <Level name="Pad" column="pad" type="Integer"/>
    <Level name="Chip" column="chip" type="Integer"/>
  </Hierarchy>
  <Hierarchy name="Flash Pack Hierarchy" hasAll="true" primaryKey="chip_id">
    <Table name="chip"/>
    <Level name="Flash Pack" column="fp" type="Integer"/>
    <Level name="Pad" column="pad" type="Integer"/>
    <Level name="Chip" column="chip" type="Integer"/>
  </Hierarchy>
  <Hierarchy name="Bank Hierarchy" hasAll="true" primaryKey="chip_id">
    <Table name="chip"/>
    <Level name="Bank" column="bank" type="Integer"/>
    <Level name="Chip" column="chip" type="Integer"/>
  </Hierarchy>
</Dimension>
```

and the cube:

```
<Cube name="Chip Facts">
  <Table name="chip_facts"/>
  <DimensionUsage name="Machine" source="Machine" foreignKey="machine_id"/>
  <DimensionUsage name="Card" source="Card" foreignKey="card_id"/>
  <DimensionUsage name="Chip" source="Chip" foreignKey="chip_id"/>
  <DimensionUsage name="Failure" source="Failure" foreignKey="failure_id"/>
</Cube>
```

I can query:

```
select
  [Chip].[Reference Designator].members on columns
from [Chip Facts]
```

but not:

```
select
  [Chip].[Flash Pack].members on columns
from [Chip Facts]
```

I get:

> Caused by: mondrian.olap.MondrianException: Mondrian Error:MDX object '[Chip].[Flash Pack]' not found in cube 'Chip Facts'

How do I select the other hierarchy?

Comment: Have you tried navigating your cube using something like REX or Saiku?
Also check mondrian.log for any errors.

Comment: I don't have a mondrian.log. I'll check Saiku out.

Comment: You should have a mondrian.log, look at /path/to/mondrian/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties (or maybe log4.xml) and check where it is logging (usually `${catalina.home}/logs/mondrian.log`).

Comment: Using Saiku, I found out that the syntax is `select
  [Chip.Flash Pack Hierarchy].[Flash Pack].Members on columns
from [Chip Facts]`

Comment: It appears that officially MDX supports the [Dimension].[Hierarchy] syntax, but Mondrian's implementation doesn't let you use the brackets.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144820

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax mondrian Olap cube

```
select {[Measures.qty1],..} on rows,
{[dimension.heirrarchy].members} on columns
from cube
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
select [Chip].[Flash Pack Hierarchy].[Flash Pack].members on 0 from [Chip Facts]
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, but I just get: mondrian.olap.MondrianException: Mondrian Error:MDX object '[Chip].[Flash Pack Hierarchy].[Flash Pack]' not found in cube 'Chip Facts'

Answer (score 0):

The first hierarchy has no name, this is the default hierarchy. 
The second hierarchy is [Flash Pack Hierarchy], the name is required.

Comment: See Marc Polizzi's answer; I tried including the hierarchy name in the select statement, but it didn't work.